# Duplicate img when creating custom skeleton component modals

Tags: svelte, skeleton-ui

I am using `skeleton@0.86.9`, svelte-kit and tailwind.
I want to create a custom component modal (see https://www.skeleton.dev/utilities/modals at "component modals") to display an image. The modal gets called via a function, that also passes the specific img url.
**The Problem:** When opening the modal, the image gets displayed twice. 1. The image as if I had no custom componed provided and 2. The custom img rendered by the `img` html tag with my custom styles. I'd only like to display the second one.

The codeblock calling the modal function:

```html
<div
            on:click="{() => componentModal({ image: image })}"
            class="image h-56 w-56 shrink-0 rounded bg-cover duration-300"
            style="background-image: url({image})"
          ></div>
```

The modal function itself:

```
export const componentModal = (settings: Partial<ModalSettings>): Promise<void> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    modalStore.trigger({
      type: 'component',
      component: { ref: FileModal },
      image: '/favicon.png',
      response: (r) => (r ? resolve() : reject()),
      ...settings,
    });
  });
```

The `FileModal.svelte`:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { modalStore } from '@skeletonlabs/skeleton';

  const cImage = 'max-w-[90%] max-h-[90%] rounded-container-token overflow-hidden shadow-xl';
</script>

{#if $modalStore[0]}
  <!-- Image -->
  <img src="{$modalStore[0].image}" class="{cImage}" alt="Example" />
{/if}
```

Also, I get two warnings in the browser console:

1. `<FileModal> received an unexpected slot "default"`
2. `<FileModal> was created with unknown prop 'parent'`
   The latter pbl only has to do with the fact that I don't have an `export let parent...` set in `FileModal.svelte`

Comment: Please create a reproduction using https://sveltelab.dev or a git repo and we can help you further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, one should use the right version of skeleton (i.e. `1.10.x`).

It seems the `type: component` was just not supported at `v0.89.6`.